# Multiple table select query error

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am having a bit of trouble outputing the mail trash section of my website, the reason for this is because i am trying to get data from two different tables in one select query, i know it is easy to do, but for somereason whenever i try i keep getting the error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arken\mail.php on line 285
```

Here is the top part of the code for selecting (the reason for the split in the statement is for the use of pagination)

```
$trash_statement = "user_inbox, user_outbox WHERE (user_inbox.receiver_user_id='$user_id' AND user_inbox.mail_deleted ='1') OR WHERE (user_outbox.sender_user_id='$user_id' AND user_outbox.mail_deleted ='1')";
```

And here is the code that is in the main section of the page

```
<?php 
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$trash_statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) : ?>
```

And after that is just the php/html for displaying the records.

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem, i have tried everything.

Thanks

Edit: ok i have tried it once again in the sql and i get the right results, which should be 3 from the user_inbox and 2 from the the user_outbox, however, it is for somereason duplicating the results so for the user_inbox i am getting the 3 records twice and from the user_outbox i am getting the 2 records 3 times, which means i am getting 12 results when i should only be getting 5.  Here is the new query any ideas? `SELECT * FROM user_inbox, user_outbox WHERE user_inbox.receiver_user_id='4' AND user_inbox.mail_deleted ='1' AND user_outbox.sender_user_id='4' AND user_outbox.mail_deleted ='1'`

Comment: what about echoing your query?

Comment: ok, i get this `SELECT * FROM user_inbox, user_outbox WHERE (user_inbox.receiver_user_id='4' AND user_inbox.mail_deleted ='1') OR (user_outbox.sender_user_id='4' AND user_outbox.mail_deleted ='1')`

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a [`cross join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) instead of a [`union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html).

Using a `cross join` means that you get one result for each combination of your inbox/outbox records that match your `where` conditions. Since you have 2 inbox matches and 3 outbox matches, you get 6 results (where each result contains one inbox result and one outbox result). If you have something deleted in the inbox but not the outbox, then you would get no results with your query, even though you have the one deletion.

*UPDATE*

As per the document I linked, a union statement looks like

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

Since I don't know your table structure, I can't give you an exact query. You will probably want to include a flag so you know if the data is from the inbox table or outbox table. Something like:

```
(SELECT 0 AS inoutFlg, receiver_user_id AS user_id, mail_deleted
 FROM user_inbox
 WHERE receiver_user_id = '4' and mail_deleted = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 1 AS inoutFlg, sender_user_id AS user_id, mail_deleted
 FROM user_outbox
 WHERE sender_user_id = '4' and mail_deleted = 1)
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}
```

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, but how might i structure the query with a union?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a step. You have to do:

```
$query = "whatever query";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //whatever you want to do here...
    //$row['column name'] is the format of the data that you'd be getting
}
```

That works for me every time. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but i do that part here `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$trash_statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");` and then use the mysql_fetch_assoc afterwards

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't see that. Have to tried mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc? Also, what is the proper thing to do here? Should I delete my response since I guess it's not quite correct?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking mysql_error()? or just running the mysql query manually against the DB using i.e. phpMyAdmin?

```
$error = mysql_error();
if(!empty($error)){ echo 'errno: ' . mysql_errno() . ' msg: ' . $error; }
```